# php5-openssl package for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: php

dev_appserver.py doesn't support php7. I've installed php5.6 from ppa:ondrej/php, but I cannot find an openssl loadable module. Packages php5-openssl and php5.6-openssl don't seem to exist.

Where can I find a compatible PHP openssl module?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need openssl module, it's built-in:

```
$ php5.6 -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i openssl
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
php -i | grep -i openssl
```

to see if OpenSLL has been installed before, it seems that the OpenSLL extension is installed by default...